# scale (zoom) screen - jQuery Mobile / jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, scale, zooming

I'am working on jQueryMobile application.

This is what it looks like when I start the page:

[image]

And this is how it looks like when I zoom the screen with scrolling on the mouse:

[image]

Is it possible to change the initial zooming / scaling so that my initial zooming to be set as the second screenshot attached? When starting the application I want the screen to be zoomed at 250 %.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the css zoom on the body to 2.5?

```
style="zoom: 2.5;"
```

Comment: I already tried that, but it is not working. I'am still getting the first screenshot on my initial page.

Comment: Can do using css. I've amended my answer. ^_^